# using Matplotlib animation to simulate pendulum on a cart

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

For me, The solution of the dynamical system looks good, but the visualization has a bug and I can't find it, I appreciate your help. I defined two shapes, the first is a circle and simulates the tip of the pendulum and second, is a rectangle and simulates the cart. The rectangle doesn't show at all in the animation. Moreover, I want a line that connect the cart(rectangle) with the circle.

```
import numpy
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def cart_pend(t, x, pend_mass, cart_Mass, L, g, d, u):
    """

    This function is to idenstify the our equations that link our states to the inputs

    """

    Sx = numpy.sin(x[2])
    Cx = numpy.cos(x[2])
    D = pend_mass * L * L * (cart_Mass + pend_mass * (1 - Cx**2))

    dx1_dt = x[1]
    dx2_dt = (1 / D) * (
        -(pend_mass**2) * L**2 * g * Cx * Sx
        + pend_mass * L**2 * (pend_mass * L * x[3] ** 2 * Sx - d * x[1])
    ) + pend_mass * L * L * (1 / D) * u
    dx3_dt = x[3]
    dx4_dt = (1 / D) * (
        (pend_mass + cart_Mass) * pend_mass * g * L * Sx
        - pend_mass * L * Cx * (pend_mass * L * x[3] ** 2 * Sx - d * x[1])
    ) - pend_mass * L * Cx * (1 / D) * u

    return [dx1_dt, dx2_dt, dx3_dt, dx4_dt]


m = 1
M = 5
L = 2
g = -10
d = 1
tspan = (1.0, 10.0)
x0 = [0, 0, numpy.pi, 0.5]
print("the shape of initial state vector is", numpy.shape(x0))
sol = solve_ivp(lambda t, x: cart_pend(t, x, m, M, L, g, d, -1), tspan, x0)
t = sol.t
y1, y2, y3, y4 = sol.y

print("Time points:", t)
print("Solution for y1:", y1)
print("Solution for y2:", y2)

plt.plot(t, y1, label="y1")
plt.plot(t, y2, label="y2")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("State Variables")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

#fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#(line,) = ax.plot([], [], "b")
#
#
#def init():
#    ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
#    ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
#    return (line,)
#
#
#def update(frame):
#    line.set_data(y1[:frame], y2[:frame])
#    return (line,)
#
#
#ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(t), init_func=init, blit=True)
#ani.save("simulation.gif", writer="Pillow")
#
#plt.show()


# Initialize figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

# Initialize shapes
shape1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.1, color='red')
shape2 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0.2, 0.2, color='blue')

def init():
    shape1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.1, color='red')
    shape2 = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0.2, 0.2, color='blue')
    return   shape1, shape2


# Update function to compute new positions
def update(frame):
    theta = sol.y[0, frame]
    x = sol.y[2, frame]
    shape1.center = (numpy.sin(theta), numpy.cos(theta))
    shape2.set_xy([x - 0.1, -0.1])
    return shape1, shape2

# Animation function
def animate(frame):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
    ax.add_patch(shape1)
    ax.add_patch(shape2)
    return update(frame)

# Create animation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=sol.y.shape[1], interval=100, blit=True)

# Display the animation
plt.show()

# Convert animation to HTML format
html_anim = anim.to_jshtml()

# Save animation to an HTML file
with open("animation.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(html_anim)

# Display the animation
plt.close()
```

Comment: What are each of the values in the solution? i.e. what are y1, y2, y3, and y4 representing?

Comment: Thanks, They represent the states of the system, y1 is the pendulum angular position. y2 is the pendulum angular velocity, y3 is the cart position, y4 is the cart velocity

Answer (score 0):

To show the patches and update them, you must add the patches to the axes and update the coordinates in every loop. There is no need to remove the patches and re-add them to each frame. Regarding the line, you can simply create a line plot connecting the center of the circle to the center of the rectangle and update the coordinates each frame using `set_data`.

I've also passed the shapes and lines to the `animate` function, but I used `functools.partial` to make it only a function of the frame number.

That said, it seems you may have some mathematical errors, such that the simulation does not make physical sense.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from functools import partial

plt.close("all")


def cart_pend(t, x, pend_mass, cart_Mass, L, g, d, u):
    """
    This function is to idenstify the our equations that link our states to the inputs
    """
    Sx = np.sin(x[2])
    Cx = np.cos(x[2])
    D = pend_mass * L * L * (cart_Mass + pend_mass * (1 - Cx**2))

    dx1_dt = x[1]
    dx2_dt = (1 / D) * (
        -(pend_mass**2) * L**2 * g * Cx * Sx
        + pend_mass * L**2 * (pend_mass * L * x[3] ** 2 * Sx - d * x[1])
    ) + pend_mass * L * L * (1 / D) * u
    dx3_dt = x[3]
    dx4_dt = (1 / D) * (
        (pend_mass + cart_Mass) * pend_mass * g * L * Sx
        - pend_mass * L * Cx * (pend_mass * L * x[3] ** 2 * Sx - d * x[1])
    ) - pend_mass * L * Cx * (1 / D) * u

    return [dx1_dt, dx2_dt, dx3_dt, dx4_dt]


m = 1
M = 5
L = 2
g = -10
d = 1
tspan = (1.0, 10.0)
t = np.linspace(*tspan, 100)
x0 = [0, 0, np.pi, 0.5]
print("the shape of initial state vector is", np.shape(x0))
sol = solve_ivp(cart_pend, tspan, x0, args=(m, M, L, g, d, -1), t_eval=t)
theta, omega, x, v = sol.y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, theta, label="theta")
ax.plot(t, omega, label="omega")
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("State Variables")
fig.legend()
ax.grid()
fig.show()


# Initialize figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_aspect(1)

shape1 = plt.Circle((np.sin(theta[0]), np.cos(theta[0])), 0.1, color='red')
width = 0.4
height = 0.2
shape2 = plt.Rectangle((x[0] - width/2, 0), width, height, color='blue')
line, = ax.plot([],[], "k")

ax.add_patch(shape1)
ax.add_patch(shape2)

def animate(frame, shape1, shape2, line, theta, x):
    shape1.center = (np.sin(theta[frame]), np.cos(theta[frame]))
    shape2.set_xy((x[frame] - width/2, 0))
    
    x1, y1 = shape1.center
    x2, y2 = shape2.xy[0] + width/2, height/2
    line.set_data([x1, x2], [y1, y2])
    return shape1, shape2, line

animate = partial(animate, 
                  shape1=shape1, 
                  shape2=shape2, 
                  line=line, 
                  theta=theta, x=x)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=sol.y.shape[1], 
                               interval=100, blit=True)

fig.show()
```

[image]

The cart is all the way to the right because you seemed to have initialized its location at `np.pi`.